# Drive is not accessible (The file or dir is corrupted and unreadable). CHKDSK aborts. What else?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk

I have a "[drive letter]:\ is not accessible. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable" problem with one of the partitions on my external hard-drive.

"chkdsk /f [drive letter]:" won't solve it. It says: "Unable to determine volume version and state. CHKDSK aborted."

What else can I do to fix it or at least partially recover my data?

Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what your working with, what kind of device it is and what you have available. While your tags do indicate Windows 7 and some form of hard disk drive you never really mention it in your question. What happened to the disk before this started to happen? What else have you tried?

Comment: @Seth Hello, Seth. Thank you very much for your question. 1) Yes, I use Windows 7 (SP1 x86), the device is some Seagate Barracuda 1TB (I don't remember the model and in system it's seen just as USB 3.0 External Device). Also, Diskpart > list volume says that format of the  partition is RAW and its status is Healthy. 2) Nothing really happened with it before, I mean it simply worked. Actually, it's quite old and had been working for quite some time. And that is the only reason I can see for the issue. I have yet to buy a new drive, so I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get another hard drive, and then run one of many software recovery products.

Testdisk or photorec by cgsecurity

Free, and it recovers data, but typically butchers the filenames.

GetDataBack for NTFS, or Rstudio, or one of dozens of other paid products.

Answer (score 0):

systemrescuecd and ddrescue.

That will create an image e.g. say you call it `blah.a`

You'll need to use some linux knowledge.. like `fdisk -l` to see what drives are detected...  You could connect the drive to USB or connect it internally. No need to mount it, don't mount it even, probably better not to mount it. Then you can tell ddrescue to copy from that, to a destination file image.

Once you have an image then you can run testdisk on that image.  `testdisk blah.a`

It can take eg a few hours for the image 'cos it has to do the entire drive. It's much slower than eg macrium.